# Calling UpdateWindow from outside WM_PAINT in Win32?

Tags: winapi

I am a beginner at Win32 and have a tough time getting the window to redraw itself when I want to. I suspect it has something to do with that I am trying to use
InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, FALSE); 
UpdateWindow(hWnd);

within the CALLBACK WndProc    WM_COMMAND  function i.e. outside WM_PAINT. Is it the case that the window will not update itself immediately and that it will instead pile up all the redraw calls and wait until 'later' when WM_PAINT is called?

Thank you!

Comment: With your current phrasing you only attract answerers who know the painting routines and order by heart. If you want others to have a try at it, you may want to read [ask] and provide a [mcve], which I think is possible within a line or 10 of code.

Comment: If you read how painting works, you'd understand why it is this way, why it is as designed that painting occurs when the message queue is empty, and WM_PAINT messages are synthesised for any invalid regions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: [UpdateWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145167.aspx) *"[...] sends a WM_PAINT message directly to the window procedure of the specified window, **bypassing the application queue**."*

Comment: @IInspectable I know.

Comment: That is what I thought but it doesn't seem to do that when I put InvalidateRect followed by UpdateWindow inside WM_COMMAND. Anyways thanks for your replies!

Comment: Again, if you read how painting works on Windows, you'll see why you need to call `InvalidateRect()` first.

Comment: @andlabs So is "read a book" the default answer to Winapi beginner level questions?

Comment: `So is "read a book" the default answer to Winapi beginner level questions?` Not any book, find Petzold's Programming Windows 5th edition.

Comment: @Johan for your question, not necessarily a book, though the Petzold book certainly does help. MSDN will also explain window painting. For learning Windows programming in general, the Petzold book is probably the best approach.

Comment: Ok thank you for your tips :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it the case that the window will not update itself immediately and that it will instead pile up all the redraw calls and wait until 'later' when WM_PAINT is called?

No, this is *not* the case.

What you described is basically how painting *normally* works, and that is what would happen if you had simply called `InvalidateRect`. The window's client area would have simply been marked as "invalid" and a `WM_PAINT` message would have been sent when there are otherwise no messages waiting in the queue to be processed. The only thing your description gets wrong is that the painting/redrawing calls don't "pile up". If you call `InvalidateRect` 20 times, you will only get 1 `WM_PAINT` message. The idea behind this "lazy" painting strategy is that painting is a low-priority, yet expensive, operation, and that "eagerly" painting would lead to a bunch of wasted cycles—you might paint something that is only going to be repainted over a few microseconds later.

But the fact that you called `UpdateWindow` changes all of that. This instruction forces a repaint to occur *immediately*. As [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145167.aspx) says:

> The UpdateWindow function updates the client area of the specified window by sending a `WM_PAINT` message to the window if the window's update region is not empty. The function sends a `WM_PAINT` message directly to the window procedure of the specified window, bypassing the application queue. If the update region is empty, no message is sent.

The initial call to `InvalidateRect` marked the window's client area as invalid, thus creating a non-empty "update region" for the window. The subsequent call to `UpdateWindow` noticed that this window was in need of repainting, and forced the repaint to occur *immediately* by sending the window procedure a `WM_PAINT` message directly, bypassing the normal message queue.

Normally, there is no reason to call `UpdateWindow`. Let the window manager handle sending painting messages when it determines that it is an appropriate time to repaint. The only time you would ever need to call `UpdateWindow` is if you're doing something like an expensive computation in response to a different message. That would block the UI thread, keeping any other messages from being processed, including `WM_PAINT` messages. This is a **bad** thing to do for many reasons. One of them is that it keeps your window from being repainted. Another more serious problem is that it causes your application to become unresponsive from the user's perspective, because it stops responding to input messages. If you need to do some time-consuming calculation, do it on a background thread.

But there *are* a handful of cases where you might want to call `UpdateWindow`. I've used it a few times, and it works exactly as described above. I have no idea why you are having trouble getting it to work; you forgot to include a code sample that reproduces the problem in your question.

> it doesn't seem to do that when I put InvalidateRect followed by UpdateWindow inside WM_COMMAND

It absolutely does not matter that this is done in the `WM_COMMAND` message handler. You could be doing it from anywhere. The important thing is that you first cause some portion of the window's client area to become invalid (which you accomplish with `InvalidateRect`), and then force the repaint of that invalid area to occur immediately (which you accomplish with `UpdateWindow`).

If I had to speculate as to your problem, it would be that your repaint *is* getting immediately triggered, the window *is* getting repainted, but then by the time you get to see it, another repaint has already occurred and your changes are being painted over. This would suggest a bug in your `WM_PAINT` handling logic, but as I said, we cannot see it, so this is just a guess.

Comment: Ok thank you for a pedagogical answer, I'm getting there now; it's just like you said that the repaint got immediately triggered. I didn't post the source code because its long and I figured it was something basic, which it was.

Comment: The basic rule here on Stack Overflow is to post a [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem you're having. It is, of course, true that it takes work to generate such an example, and it is also true that the process of generating this example often results in you figuring out the problem for yourself. This is all by design. :-) But really, it is the only way we can help you. The only alternative is some long, rambly answer that tries to teach you everything relevant about a particular API, which most people won't take the time to write and is rarely very helpful for solving a specific problem. @joh

Answer (score -1):

In case some other newbie has similar problems it might be useful to put in Sleep(2000) before your InvalidateRect's together with a string output about where you currently are, that way you'll have no doubt about what happens when. At least that's how I found my problem...

Comment: Pretty much the *last* thing you should do when debugging UI applications, and especially painting problems, is insert calls to `Sleep`. The function is only useful in very isolated unusual situations, but newbie programmers tend to abuse it. This is far more likely to trip you up than to help you. I guess it's pretty much fair to put anything you want in for debugging purposes, so long as you remove it and test the program thoroughly before release. But still, `Sleep` can often lead you to invalid or meaningless conclusions. I wouldn't recommend it as a strategy.

Comment: What *does* make good sense, though, is outputting some kind of state/location information. A `MessageBox` obviously won't work in UI code, because that disrupts drawing operations. But `OutputDebugString` works very nicely. You can view this output either in a dedicated debug trace viewer, like DebugView, or you can view it directly in Visual Studio, since it redirects this output either to the Output Window or the Immediate Window. *Extremely* handy!

Comment: @CodyGray: For debugging purposes I find [tracepoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx#Anchor_12) even more convenient, than `OutputDebugString`. They don't require any code changes, and allow you to dump variable contents. This is particularly helpful in analyzing the order of calls.